# Create react app build - system ran out of memory

Tags: reactjs, openshift, create-react-app

I'm using openshift clouds for my React App (Created by CRA).
And get I this error. In app I have pretty big file (2.9Mb) but I imported this file only one time when app is mounted.

So I have to question:

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. How in openshift I ca just push build that I have made in my local machine?

ERROR:

```
FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! clocks@2.0.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the clocks@2.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Comment: It's unclear both what you mean by "openshift clouds" (there is no such product) and how you are trying to deploy (i.e. where this error is even getting reported). Perhaps from S2I? But you probably need to edit your question to provide more clarity on exactly what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

1. Found a temporary solution.
2. Transferred the build to the local machine.
3. In the dockerfile specifies only to create a working folder and copy
   the folder build, then start the project.
4. Push build to gh repo.
5. Build project.  Done.